# Eliminar un dato de select tomado de una tabla

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Buen día foro, tengo la siguiente duda y es saber si puedo eliminar un dato de un select, tomado una tabla generada con php.

**La tabla es la siguiente.**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta el momento se puede observar que van dos registros, el dato a tomar en cuenta es el que esta encerrado en el rectángulo **rojo**.

Ahora les muestro el modal donde dentro esta un pequeño formulario, ahí es donde esta mi select con la información, me gustaría que en ese select ya no existieran los dos datos que ya tengo en mi tabla, que son los que marque en color rojo anteriormente y ahora en mi modal se los marco en verde.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta tabla es generada con PHP y consultas en MYSQL.

El select de momento lo tengo con valores definidos lo dejo aquí.

```
<select name="psb_hr" id="psb_hr" class="form-control">
                        <option value disabled selected>Seleccione una opcion...</option>
                        <option value="04">06:40 - 07:00</option>
                        <option value="05">07:00 - 08:00</option>
                        <option value="06">08:00 - 09:00</option>
                        <option value="07">09:00 - 10:00</option>
                        <option value="08">10:00 - 11:00</option>
                        <option value="09">11:00 - 12:00</option>
                        <option value="10">12:00 - 13:00</option>
                        <option value="11">13:00 - 14:00</option>
                        <option value="12">14:00 - 15:00</option>
                        <option value="13">15:00 - 16:10</option>
                        <option value="14">16:10 - 17:00</option>
                        <option value="15">17:00 - 18:00</option>
                        <option value="16">18:00 - 19:00</option>
                        <option value="17">19:00 - 20:00</option>
                        <option value="18">20:00 - 21:00</option>
                        <option value="19">21:00 - 22:16</option>
                        <option value="20">22:16 - 23:00</option>
                        <option value="21">23:00 - 00:00</option>
                        <option value="22">00:00 - 01:00</option>
                        <option value="23">01:00 - 02:00</option>
                        <option value="24">02:00 - 03:00</option>
                        <option value="25">03:00 - 04:00</option>
                        <option value="26">04:00 - 05:00</option>
                        <option value="27">05:00 - 06:00</option>
                        <option value="28">06:00 - 06:40</option>
</select>
```

Espero poder haber explicado un poco lo que quiero lograr, cualquier falta de informacion la puedo agregar,

Gracias.

Modificacion:

Ya tengo la siguiente consulta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existe la manera de meter esos datos en el arreglo que me comentaron abajo?

**$horarioActual  = '06:40 - 07:00';**

En esa variable

Comment: Falta información en tu pregunta, por ejemplo, código HTML de la tabla o el comportamiento del _select_, si se crea al abrir el modal o ya está creado y solo hay que deshabilitar / ocultar opciones usadas previamente.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías generar un array con los horarios disponibles.

```
$horarios = array(
    '06:40 - 07:00',
    '07:00 - 08:00',
    '08:00 - 09:00',
    '09:00 - 10:00',
    '10:00 - 11:00',
    '11:00 - 12:00'
);
```

Capturar el valor del horario ya utilizado.

```
$horarioActual = $valorColumnaHora;
```

Luego recorrer el array de horarios e comparar si este ya esta siendo utilizado.

```
    for ($i=0; $i<count($horarios); $i++) { 
            if($horarioActual ==$horarios[$i]){
            echo '<option value="' . $i .'">Horario Ocupado</option>';
            }else{
            echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $horarios[$i] . '</option>';
            }
    }
```

Aquí el código completo con un ejemplo

```
<?php

$horarios = array(
    '06:40 - 07:00',
    '07:00 - 08:00',
    '08:00 - 09:00',
    '09:00 - 10:00',
    '10:00 - 11:00',
    '11:00 - 12:00'
);

$horarioActual  = '06:40 - 07:00';

?>

    <select id="options" name="psb_hr" id="psb_hr" class="form-control">
        <option value disabled selected>Seleccione una opcion...</option>
        <?php
            for ($i=0; $i<count($horarios); $i++) { 
            if($horarioActual ==$horarios[$i]){
            echo '<option value="' . $i .'">Horario Ocupado</option>';
            }else{
            echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $horarios[$i] . '</option>';
            }
            }
        ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Va bien encaminada la respuesta, pero no puedes guardar el valor en una cadena, porque no se trata de uno solo, sino uno en cada fila de la tabla. Podrías crear un arreglo de horarios usados, o bien, leer las filas de la tabla.

Comment: Y si en $horarioactual quiero ocupar otra hora mas? por ejemplo de 07:00 - 08:00

Comment: En el ejemplo que puse esta comparando String, puedes agregar lo que tu desees, pero ten en cuenta a la hora de comparar tienen que ser string idénticos .

Cuando tomes el valor mediante $horarioActual lo tomara como lo especificas "07:00 - 08:00", la idea es reemplazarlo por el campo de tu base de datos

Comment: Modifique mi post para ver si me puedes ayudar,  ya mande traer la consulta con las horas que ya estan ocupadas, creo que solo seria mater esos valores en la variable $horarioactual, pero de que manera? lo intente meter tambien como un arreglo pero no funciona.

Comment: De que manera recuperas la consulta mysql? Podrías poner ese código php de respuesta